# asp.net button click not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a JavaScript code and an asp.net button control , javascript code is working fine but the asp.net button is not working for that js script

```
<asp:Button ID="loginbtn" CssClass="btn-glow primary login" OnClientClick="abc(); return false;" runat="server" Text="log in" OnClick="loginbtn_Click" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have `return false` in your `OnClientClick`. Remove it an the button will post back.

Comment: Yes this ^ the client side code runs first, so your onClientClick is running before your OnClick, thus preventing the post back, because you're returning false.

Answer (score 0):

please change the code like this

```
 <asp:Button ID="loginbtn"  OnClientClick="abc();" runat="server" Text="log in" OnClick="loginbtn_Click"/>




 function abc() {
        alert("Hi");     //put your code here
        return false;
    }
```

or

```
  function abc() {
       alert("Hi");  //put your code here          
    }
```

both will work.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your asp.net button to input button to prevent callback and make an ajax function call.

```
<input type="button" class="btn-glow primary login" onClick="abc()"/> 

function abc(){
     //ajax call
}
```

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
OnClick="loginbtn_Click"
```

with

```
OnClick="loginbtn_Click()"
```

Comment: there is an error if i use logintbn_click() -----    Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'loginbtn_Click' takes 0 arguments